# Changing emacs font (no "set default font" option in menu; .emacs scripts not working)

Tags: linux, emacs, fonts

From the many posts on how to change emacs' default font, it seems as though emacs 24 should have an option called "set default font" under Menu --> Options.  As you can see from the image below, I'm given no such option.  (The only option related to fonts is "Set default font".)  I've tried adding various scripts to my .emacs file which are intended to change the global font, yet the default persists.

I've downloaded and installed Inconsolata via sudo apt-get install fonts-inconsolata (ttf-inconsolata no longer works) and I've also run sudo fc-cache.  Given the usual answers don't seem to be working, I'm lost on what to do next...

At this point, I'm suspecting if I need to make a shell-level (or possibly system-level) change in settings in order to enable font selection on emacs (i.e., similar to ensuring that my XTERM color settings were 256 color in order to get Zenburn to work; am a Linux newbie if it isn't obvious - just trying to brainstorm here).

Version info, if helpful: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Xubuntu), emacs 24.3.1 and am launching via "emacs -nw" from the default Xubuntu shell.

Here's what I see when I go to the Menu and then select Options (i.e., pressing "F10", then "o"):

[image]

Comment: I am not a fan of the built-in customize interface and prefer to manually control how my user customization files are written / organized.  To do it manually, you may wish to have a look at the Emacs documentation for attribute functions:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html

Comment: Here is something I use on OSX -- for some reason the `default-frame-alist` never seems to catch the font for the initial frame, so `set-face-attribute` is needed for that one -- the `default-frame-alist` catches all subsequent frames:  `(set-face-attribute 'default (selected-frame) :font "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1") (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")) (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "black")) (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(foreground-color . "white"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that Emacs can't change the font of the terminal. It can only set the colour (and possibly adding bold and underline properties). This is true for all console mode programs. You need to run Emacs in GUI mode to enable full font selection.